# Cardinality of Distinct Hilbert Systems with Detachment

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, propositional-calculus

Let us consider all formulas **T** of classical propositional logic which are tautologies up to simple substitution of variables where a variable can get simply substituted for another variable if and only if the variable is uniformly substituted by another variable (α-equivalence?).  Suppose we consider the class of axiom sets **A** of **T**, and we have a rule of detachment which says 
$X(x, y), x\vdash y$.  The cardinality of **A** can quickly shown to be at least $2^{\aleph_0}$ (consider a system such as $\{CpCNpq\}$ which can get seen to have infinitely many theorems using condensed detachment.  Demonstration: Since the consequent has a variable not in the antecedent, it is possible to introduce a new variable for each theorem proven using $\mathsf{D1}x$, where $x$ is the theorem previously proven using condensed detachment.  Then write a bijection from the theorems of $\{CpCNpq\}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ using $q$ for the first element of $\mathbb{N}$, and the new variables introduced by each new theorem for every other element of $\mathbb{N}$.  Since **A** is P(**T**), and the theorems of $\{CpCNpq\}$ is an infinite subset of P(**T**), and P($\mathbb{N}$) has cardinality of $2^{\aleph_0}$, it follows that **A** has cardinality of $2^{\aleph_0}$).

But, some sets of **A** are inter-derivable from other sets of **A**, in the sense that axiom set **X** can get used to derive all the axioms of set **Y** and axiom set **Y** can derive all the axioms of set **X**.  So, what is the cardinality of all subsets of **A**, **A**' which are not inter-derivable from any other set of **A**'?

Comment: Perhaps the TeX command `\mathbf` could be of some use to you?

Comment: @Lord_Farin Thanks for the advice.  It helped me look more into LaTex.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence **S** defined as (Cpp, CCppCpp, CCCppCppCCppCpp, ...) where each term (n+1) is term n substituting p with Cpp.  For axiom system {(n+1), detachment rule} it is impossible to detach axiom n, since the first detached theorem D11 is 1, making all subsequent theorems also 1.  We thus have an infinite sequence of theorems where the system corresponding to the first theorem with detachment can derive the second, the second the third, etc. but not conversely.  It also holds that theorem (n+2) cannot derive theorem n since the first detached theorem has p substituted with the antecedent of (n+2).  By induction it follows that no theorem (n+k) can derive theorem n.  And from CCppCpp since the varaible substituted for is p, and Cpp gets substituted for p using condensed detachment, and no other substitutions are possible, it follows that Cpp cannot derived from CCppCpp.  In other words, Cpp is more general than CCppCpp.  So, by induction (rewriting the "cannot derive" arguments in terms of generality), it follows that every axiom in this sequence is either more general or less general than every other axiom of the sequence.  Thus, every member of the power set without the empty set, of this sequence of sets has at least one theorem not inter-derivable from any other subset of axioms of any other subset of axioms.  Since we can readily make a bijection of **S** with the natural numbers here, it follows that P(**S**) has cardinality of $2^{\aleph_0}$.  Since P(**S**) is a subset of **A'** it follows that **A'** has cardinality of at least $2^{\aleph_0}$.

(I'm not certain the reasoning here works).